# Converter array php

Tags: php, array

Como faço para transformar esse *array*:

```
$rs = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DESCRICAO] => cadastrar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DESCRICAO] => editar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DESCRICAO] => deletar
        )

)
```

em

```
array(cadastrar,editar,deletar)
```

Estou tentando fazer:

```
$permissao = 'editar';

if(in_array($permissao ,$rs)){
  $permissao = true;
}else {
  $permissao = false;
}
```

Comment: O que tentou fazer? Qual foi o resultado obtido? O que sabe de PHP?

Comment: Este é o retorno das permissões do banco de dados. Preciso na programação verificar se o usuário tem determinada permissão, para isso utilizo in_array. Em relação ao PHP  sou iniciante.

Comment: Certo, mas já tentou fazer a conversão que deseja? Qual foi o resultado obtido? Deu erro? Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar a sua tentativa?

Comment: Tentei fazer sim. Alterei no PDO de fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) para fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) adicionando return $rs ->DESCRICAO.

Comment: Coloque **na pergunta** o código que tentou fazer e descreva o que aconteceu, por favor.

Comment: Tentei também, jogando a varável no foreach pegando apenas o valor, e nada tbm.

Comment: Esse array `$rs` vem do banco? usa o PDO para recuperar as informações?

Comment: Realmente foi duplicata. O array_map resolveu. Obrigado Anderson Calors Woss

Answer (score 1):

Pode formatar (flatten) esse array com PDO o primeiro passo é sua consulta deve retornar apenas dois campos sendo o primeiro o id (chave do array) e o segundo o valor. Na hora de recuperar as os dados use a constante `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAR` em `fetch()/fetchAll()`

O array que normalmente seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [descricao] => new
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [descricao] => edit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [descricao] => delete
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [descricao] => update
        )

)
```

Vira:

```
Array
(
    [1] => new
    [2] => edit
    [3] => delete
    [4] => update
)
```

Código fica da seguinte forma (com uma pequena otimização)

```
$rs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

$acao = 'editar';
$permissao = in_array($acao ,$rs, true);
```